# Is there any lodash function to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array

```
var a = [
   {id: 1, item: 3}, 
   {id: 1, item: 4}, 
   {id: 1, item: 5}, 
   {id: 2, item: 6}, 
   {id: 2, item: 7}, 
   {id: 3, item: 8}
]
```

I need output like this:

```
[{id: 1, items: [3, 4, 5]}, {id: 2, items: [6,7]}, {id: 3, items: [8]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that first groups by `id` and then maps across the groupings to get the required collection:

```
let result = _(a)
    .groupBy('id')
    .map( (group ,id) => ({id: id, items: _.map(group, 'item')}))
    .value()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty ugly, but then other answers are not pretty either

```js
var a = [
   {id: 1, item: 3}, 
   {id: 1, item: 4}, 
   {id: 1, item: 5}, 
   {id: 2, item: 6}, 
   {id: 2, item: 7}, 
   {id: 3, item: 8}
];

var ret = _.chain(a)
   
   .groupBy(elt => elt.id)
   .mapValues(elt => _.reduce(elt, (acc, sub) => acc.concat(sub.item),[]))
   .map((value, key) => ({id: key, items:value}))
   
   .value();
console.log(ret);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```